# Angular make request on key Press

Tags: angular

How to make an HTTP request on keypress event with the input, for now, I'm getting undefines as a result.

code below

**app.component.html**

```
<input
  id="search"
  type="text"
  placeholder=" search"
  value=""
  (keyup.enter)="searchData()"
  name="search"
/>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  searchData(value: string) {

    this.results = this.googleService.getGoogle(value)
      .subscribe(x => {

        this.Data = x.items;
        console.log('Data', this.Data);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the input value as parameter of the function `searchData`

Check how to do that in the Angular documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter

With that approach, you should modify your code as follow:

app.component.html

```
 <input #inputField id="search" type="text" placeholder=" search" value=""
            (keyup.enter)="searchData(inputField.value)" name="search" />
```

app.component.ts

```
    searchData(value:string) { 
        this.results = this.googleService.getGoogle(value)
        .subscribe(x = > { this.Data = x.items;
         console.log('Data', this.Data);
    }
```

Check that we pass the value of the input to the function `searchData` through template references: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-a-template-reference-variable

Comment: Great work @GermanQuinteros  that's actually working for me as I want :)

Comment: I have another  question with this approach if I want to bind to also a button so they all perform the same task either the enter key press or the button clicked,

Comment: Happy to know that this works for you.
In that case, you can use the same function and the template reference too:
```<input #inputField id="search" type="text" placeholder="search" value=""(keyup.enter)="searchData(inputField.value)" name="search" />
<button (click)="searchData(inputField.value)"></button>```

Answer (score 1):

You can create local variable and pass input value to your function.

```
<input
  #inputEl
  id="search"
  type="text"
  placeholder=" search"
  value=""
  (keyup.enter)="searchData(inputEl.value)"
  name="search"      
/>
```

Now you can see input value in searchData function

Answer (score 1):

You can add `[(ngModel)]="search"`

Try like this:

```
 <input id="search" type="text" placeholder=" search" 
           [(ngModel)]="search" (keyup.enter)="searchData(search)" name="search" />
```

.ts

```
searchData(value: string) {
   this.results = this.googleService.getGoogle(value)
    .subscribe(x = > { this.Data = x.items;
     console.log('Data', this.Data);
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djetnj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: kindly explain how i would implement your solution in the http request

Comment: oh nice, I like your approach as well and it's actually working as I want it to.
btw i would like to ask if you want to apply the function to click events it can perform either by **keypress** or a **button click event**.  so what I did was to `searchData(value)` and it doesn't work well for me

Comment: i think i got it working i place the ng variable in searchData parameter and it's working now. Thank you for assistance

Answer (score 1):

Pass the entered value from the event target:

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder=" search" value=""
            (keyup.enter)="searchData($event.target.value)" name="search" />
```

And check if the value exists before making a call:

```
searchData(value: string) {
  if (!value) {
    return;
  }

  this.results = this.googleService.getGoogle(value)
     .subscribe(x => {
       this.Data = x.items;
       console.log('Data', this.Data);
 }
```

Comment: nice, nice new idea from @Maihan, i love that.